# How do I programmatically open a folder in the Finder without selecting anything?

Tags: macos, cocoa

When the user clicks a button in my application I want to have the Finder come to the front and display the contents of a folder. The `NSWorkspace` class has two calls, `activateFileViewerSelectingURLs(:)` and `selectFile(:inFileViewerRootedAtPath:)`, that almost do what I want, but they both select one or more items. I don't want the Finder to select anything.

I see the behavior I want if I enter

```
/usr/bin/open /path/to/my/folder
```

in Terminal. Is there a Cocoa API for doing this, or do I need to have `NSTask` run `/usr/bin/open`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It suffices to ask the workspace to open the folder as a file, because the Finder is the default app for folders. For example:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.open(
    URL(
        fileURLWithPath: "/System/Library/CoreServices",
        isDirectory: true
    )
)
```

(The `isDirectory` parameter is optional but passing it saves a system call.)

Comment: how to get permission to open the path?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be sure to have the Finder open the folder regardless of the default app settings, you could use Applescript:

```
NSString *script = [NSString StringWithFormat: 
    @“tell application \”Finder\”\nopen folder (\“%@\” as POSIX file)\nend tell\n”, path];

NSAppleScript *openScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource: script];
[openScript executeAndReturnError:nil];
```

Comment: Nice hack via AppleScript!

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work any more, with or without tabs.

Answer (score 1):

AppleScript was a solution for me, but I had to add tabs (`\t`) for it to work:

```
NSString* path = ...;
NSString* script = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tell application \"Finder\"\n\tactivate\n\tmake new Finder window to (POSIX file \"%@\")\nend tell\n", path];
NSAppleScript* openScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:script];
[openScript executeAndReturnError:nil];
```

so that resulting script looks like:

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    make new Finder window to (POSIX file "/Users/MyUser/someFolder")
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(fileURLWithPath: "/your/path/goes/here"))
```

Note that you have to have read permissions for the path that you want to open.